# Is all of $\mathbb{R}$ the only open set containing $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Is all of $\mathbb{R}$ the only open set containing $\mathbb{Q}$?

False, take any irrational $p$ in $\mathbb{R}$. Then $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{R} \setminus \{p\}$ and $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{p\}$ is open.

Of course we can take any subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ that is closed in $\mathbb{R}$ and take $\mathbb{R} \setminus A$.

Is what I got right? or did I forget something?

What fact or theorem can I use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. What you have written is correct. In fact, you can do much better in the sense that you can cover $\mathbb{Q}$ with open set with arbitrarily small length $\epsilon$, for instance $$\mathbb{Q}_{\text{open cover}} = \bigcup_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(q_k - \dfrac{\epsilon}{2^{k+2}},q_k + \dfrac{\epsilon}{2^{k+2}} \right)$$